# Android checkstyle OperatorWrap error

Tags: android, android-studio, checkstyle

I'm trying to add the OperatorWrap on checkstyle config, but when I do that and run the checkstyle I'm getting the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkstyle'.
Unable to create a Checker: configLocation {/home/user/Workspace/project/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml}, classpath {null}.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

This is my checkstyle file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
    "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
    http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<module name="Checker">
    <property name="charset" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="severity" value="error" />
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="OperatorWrap">
            <property name="option" value="NL"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="BAND, BOR, BSR, BXOR, DIV, EQUAL, GE, GT, LAND, LE, LITERAL_INSTANCEOF, LOR, LT, MINUS, MOD, NOT_EQUAL, PLUS, QUESTION, SL, SR, STAR, METHOD_REF "/>
        </module>
    </module>
</module>
```

Comment: Which version of Checkstyle are you using?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `"NL"` with `"nl"` in `<property name="option" value="NL"/>`? Not sure if caps make a difference there.

Comment: We would need the entire stack trace to determine the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?xml version="1.0"?>` is not needed and you are missing a `"` before `http://www.puppycrawl.com`.

Below is the valid XML configuration file as long as you are using Checkstyle version 7.2+:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
    "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<module name="Checker">
    <property name="charset" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="severity" value="error" />
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="OperatorWrap">
            <property name="option" value="NL"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="BAND, BOR, BSR, BXOR, DIV, EQUAL, GE, GT, LAND, LE, LITERAL_INSTANCEOF, LOR, LT, MINUS, MOD, NOT_EQUAL, PLUS, QUESTION, SL, SR, STAR, METHOD_REF "/>
        </module>
    </module>
</module>
```

Comment: Due to Checkstyle [#6478](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/6478) the correct DTD link is now: `<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
  "-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN"
  "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">`